# Где правильно требуется поставить скобки в выражении? с++

Tags: c++

[image: Выражение]
Как я понял из-за лишних и неправильных скобок на калькуляторе поэтому получается другой ответ, вот еще скриншот выражения без записи в программе. [image: нужное выражение]

Comment: А просто взять и самому посмотреть и посчитать - религия не позволяет?

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что должно же быть какое-то дно у вопросов на ruSO!

Comment: Ну я подсчитал с одной стороны 6 и с другой тоже, просто где-то нужно поставить еще или какие-то убрать, в этом вся суть и я не знаю где, тк кажется что все верно

Comment: Дам наводку: проблема в делении, точнее в том, на что делите

Comment: извините, я просто новичок, в делении поставить скобки??

Comment: Запомните главное -- мировой запас скобок не ограничен

Answer (score 2):

Давайте посмотрим - у вас есть

```
числитель
---------    + 0.5
знаменатель
```

Давайте начнем со знаменателя - `2sin xy`, т.е.

```
2 * sin(x*y)
```

Итак,

```
числитель
---------    + 0.5
(2 * sin(x*y))
```

Числитель - это сумма `xy^2` и квадраного корня, т.е.

```
(x*y*y + sqrt(...))
```

Заполняем эти три точки:

```
abs(x*x - 2.5e-3*y)
```

Итак, знаменатель

```
(x*y*y + sqrt(abs(x*x - 2.5e-3*y)))
```

И дробь

```
(x*y*y + sqrt(abs(x*x - 2.5e-3*y)))
------------------------------------    + 0.5
(2 * sin(x*y))
```

Осталось заменить дробь на оператор деления

```
(x*y*y + sqrt(abs(x*x - 2.5e-3*y)))/(2 * sin(x*y)) + 0.5
```

Сравнивайте с вашим выражением...